# I am trying to ingest data in druid from kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, druid

I am trying to ingest data in druid from kafka. This is how data looks like in kafka.

```
{"Machine":"CMGG-012","Time_Stamp":"1522233364000","Z2Temp":463020.0,"XTemp":630.0,"YTemp":23370.0,"ZTemp":30.0,"ATemp":101580.0,"CTemp":251010.0}
```

I am taking timestamp in milliseconds as `string`. It will work or I have to convert it into `long int`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! :) _How_ are you trying to ingest the data? Are you getting errors with your current approach?

Comment: When I check status in coordinator console .  
  {"task":"index_kafka_testMemRegV4_49d3282f55ba020_diokeike","status":{"id":"index_kafka_testMemRegV4_49d3282f55ba020_diokeike","status":"SUCCESS","duration":65132}}                                                         And in log i can see Task completed with status: {
  "id" : "index_kafka_testMemRegV4_49d3282f55ba020_diokeike",
  "status" : "SUCCESS",
  "duration" : 61164
} and then some exception occur.

Comment: But *how* are you ingesting the data? A particular tool? Console producer? And "and then some exception occur" --> *WHAT* exception? You need to provide a lot more detail if you want help :) http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: share your ingestion task json and the exact error you getting.